# Saltstack: how to configure a state that need a service running then restart this service

Tags: saltstack

I try to configure a software, by sending a command to its running service. However, to apply the new configuration, the service needs to be restarted.

How can I do that?

I tried:

```
appsrv:
  service.running:
  - enable: True

configure_app:
  cmd.run:
  - name: configure_app_command
  - unless: app_already_configured_command
  - watch_in:
    - service: appsrv
```

But it's not working, as the service is both required before and after the configuration. I also tried to use two different states: one for the service running, and one for the restart, but it was not better.

I guess I'll end up restarting the service "manually" in the `configure_app` state, just after the `configure_app_command`.

Any better way?